# NextJS: useState does not update the Value

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-hooks

For my little project I am trying to show a string, that does change when I press a button in my NextJs project.

The code I'm trying looking something like that atm:

```
'use client'
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Home() {

const [ currWord, setCurrWord ] = useState<string>("none");

return (
...
<p>{currWord}</p>
...
<button onClick={() => setCurrWord("changed")}>change</button>
...
)

}
```

If I press the Button the site, and therefore the string, does not change at all. The same happenes when its a number.
Originally I tried to run a function on that button click that does eventually set that word. But it doesn't even work like this for me, and I'm kind of wondering why, since I don't see a difference to most of the examples I find.

edit 1: since it might be relevant: Im running my Code on VSCode 1.76.2 , use NextjS 13 with the new app Folder and Typescript V 5.1.0 (also tested with V 4.6.3)

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and just added a react fragment around the returned view and it worked perfectly.
try it and tell me.

```
'use client'
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Home() {

    const [currWord, setCurrWord] = useState<string>("none");

    return (
        <>
            <p> {currWord}</p >
            <button onClick={() => setCurrWord("changed")}>change</button>
        </>
    )

}
```

Comment: Tried, sadly no difference for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).